# Mobile menu button and main menu display with jquery and css

Tags: jquery, css, hamburger-menu

I have a mobile menu button that appears below 768px wide, and when clicked it shows the menu, and when clicked again it hides the menu. However once the menu is hidden by jquery how can I show it again if the browser width is increased (eg on desktop) to over 768px. Must I use jQuery to check screen width and show above 768px or will css do it?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var h = $("#hamburger");
    h.addClass('fa fa-toggle-down');
    h.on('click', function(){
      if (h.hasClass('fa-toggle-down')) {
        h
        .removeClass('fa-toggle-down')
        .addClass('fa-toggle-up');
        $("#main-menu .module-menu").show();
      } else {
        h
        .removeClass('fa-toggle-up')
        .addClass('fa-toggle-down');
        $("#main-menu .module-menu").hide();
      }
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#hamburger {
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  color: black;
  padding: 3px 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 14px 3px 3px 3px;
  float:left;
  display:none;
}   
@media (max-width:768px){
  #hamburger {display:block}
  #main-menu .module-menu {display:none}
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="main-menu">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9"><module type="menu" /></div>
      <div class="col-md-3" id="header-search"><div id="hamburger"></div><module type="search" template="autocomplete" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use class switching, instead of `show()` and `hide()` methods. So toggling between having this class and not. And then you can choose this class to be hidden for certain resolutions.
This way you can avoid checking for screen width using jQuery, and you can rely  on css `media` queries. Here is an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/43oays2c/

Comment: But in your fiddle the 'test' which represents the menu needs to hide as browser width reduces to below 768px whereas in your test it still shows until the button is clicked.

Maybe I can hide it below 768px as in my css above, then use the button to add a class to over-ride the display setting to show?

Comment: I am currently on my mobile, but I will check tomorrow. If I understood what you meant, that can be fixed in your css. That's why I added a class, so it can be manipulated with media queries. You can hide it in css for under 768px.

Comment: Yeap, it can be done with some css changes. For example:
https://jsfiddle.net/43oays2c/1/
Basically I gave you an idea to easily manipulate the element. Everything else you can done by css (and maybe some js) changes